# Nao Python SDK 2.8 _qi.so library not found

Tags: python-2.7, nao-robot

Hello I am relatively new to NAO Python 2.8 SDK.
I am trying to go over the initial setup on a Raspberrypi running on a debian 64 bit OS which is recommended. I am running a python 2.7, also which is a prerequisite for the package. After downloading the SDK and setting it up as per the documentation, I get an error

```
ImportError: /home/pi/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.8.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_qi.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

while the path and the library exist at the location.
Neither does my locate command trace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python SDK contains native libraries that are compiled for Linux and `amd64` (*aka* Intel x64) processors. Raspberry Pis have an `arm64` processor.
The executable library `_qi.so` is reported as non-existent because it cannot execute it (that's how it's done on Linux).

The core of the framework being libQi, you can achieve the same with [libQi Python](https://github.com/aldebaran/libqi-python). You can try getting through `pip` (`pip install qi`), but it is quite probable you will need to recompile it from source.